# Call one method of inherited classes without those virtual prototype

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost

I have some base `class A`, and some number of inherited classes:

```
class B : public A
class C : public A
class D : public A
```

I have function with parsing some config file, which use name in config call:

```
void do_smth<B>(...);
void do_smth<C>(...);
void do_smth<D>(...);
```

I have `map<A*> objs;` and in those functions happend:

```
void do_smth<T>(...)
{
  T *control = new T();
  ...
  objs[name] = T;
}
```

So i have map of pointers to A. In other function I got `name`, and i need to get value stored in B,C or D classes. 
Problem is that i can't add virtual function to any class which will return those value, because of A,B,C,D from library and B have function value(), C - text(), D - currentValue() etc. And i need function `get_value()` which will return result of `value(), text(), currentValue()` depending on class?
What can you advise me to solve my problem?

I see 2 ways:

1) I can write function from pointer to classes B,C,D and call function like that `get_value((B*)objs[name]);` but i think it's not good.

2)I can create `boost::bind` object with function i need at the create B,C,D variable.

What way will be better, or could you advise me smth better?

Comment: Your controls have methods like `value()`, `text()` or `currentValue()` -- is this Qt?

Comment: It's not pure QT - some expansion of those library

Comment: If these classes use the Qt meta system (MOC, Q_OBJECT etc), you can use `QObject::metaObject()` and `QObject::inherits()` to test which class you actually have, and `qobject_cast()` to up-cast it to this class and access the appropriate value method.

Comment: Thank you - i will see for Qt object system..

Comment: @Ferdinand thank you very much. I don't know about qobject_cas<> it's very usefull for me:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have

```
A* a;
```

and don't know what type it is. Try `dynamic_cast`:

```
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
if ( b ) 
    return b->value();
//C and D the same way
```

Comment: Thx Ferdinand, that's what I meant. :)

Comment: "The second conversion in this piece of code would produce a compilation error since base-to-derived conversions are not allowed with dynamic_cast unless the base class is polymorphic." It's quote from cplusplus.com about dynamic_case<>. Could you explain what mean "Until base class is polymorphic" - what criteria is this?

Comment: That means your base class A has no virtual methods in it. And I'm not sure if static_cast would work in this case, but give it a try.

Comment: `static_cast` will do bad things when you try to convert a `A` to `B` if this `A` is actually a `C`!  Since your classes seem to inherit from `QObject`, it is better to use Qt's meta object system for type checking since it does not depend on runtime type information (RTTI).

Comment: @Olympian, sounds like you are using a lib with public inheritance but no virtual ? If this is true, that's a bad one...

Answer (score 0):

You could use type traits. Create type traits for each of your classes B,C,D to derive an "identifier" of each class (an enum value for example).Store this identifier along objs array. Later on you can switch-case this identifier to find out to which class you should cast each element in objs.

```
class A{};
class B : public A{};
class C : public A{};
class D : public A{};

enum ClassType {B_type, C_type, D_type, Unknown_type};

template<typename T>
struct Identifier{static const ClassType value = Unknown_type;};

template<>
struct Identifier<B>{static const ClassType value = B_type;};

template<>
struct Identifier<C>{static const ClassType value = C_type;};

template<>
struct Identifier<D>{static const ClassType value = D_type;};


template<typename T>
void do_smth()
{
  T *control = new T();
  ...
  objs[name] = control;
  ids[name] = Identifier<T>::value;
}

void test()
{
    do_smth<X>(); // X is of type B, C, D

    ...

    switch (ids[name])
    {
    case B_type:
        {
            B* b = static_cast<B*>(objs[name]);
            // do something with b
            break;
        }
    case C_type:
        {
            C* c = static_cast<C*>(objs[name]);
            // do something with c
            break;
        }
    case D_type:
        {
            D* d = static_cast<D*>(objs[name]);
            // do something with d
            break;
        }
    default:
        ;//error
    };      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit A to class X where you can add whatever virtual function you might need.

Then inherit X from B,C,D and use a X* for the polymorphism.